# Obtener Texto del Comando y Cadena de Conexión de un .xlsx con Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel

Estoy tratando de conseguir la cadena de conexión y la consulta de la misma dentro de un archivo `.xlsx /.xls /.xlsm`, pero estoy teniendo problemas. 
Estuve intentando con `pycom32` y `odbc`

```
import odbc
import win32com.client

xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
file = r'C:\\archivo ejemplo.xls'
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(file, None, True)
for x in wb.Connections:
    print(x.OLEDBConnection.CommandText)
xl.Application.Quit()
```

Me tira error en el `print` y estuve revisando la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oledbconnection) y el objeto `OLEDBConnection` posee la propiedad `CommandText`, el error que arroja es el siguiente :

> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, None, None,
>   None, 0, -2147467263), None)

Sin embargo, al cambiar `print(x.OLEDBConnection.CommandText)` por `print(x)` me muestra la lista con las conexiones del libro. Al parecer el error es en `OLEDBConnection`.

pd: Estoy usando `Windows` por el momento, pero una vez que lo tenga funcionando me gustaría usarlo en `Linux` (aunque no creo que sea posible por lo que vengo leyendo).